# Trying to instantiate classes dynamically

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, factory-pattern, jsch

I am trying to makeAConnection with the server using this class. This class gets the list of parameters needed to perform operation on Images in HashMaps. Then in doInBackground , I perform the operations required on Image one by one. The code for one of the classes which is OVFImage Deployer is also pasted below

```
public class ImageDeployer extends SwingWorker<Boolean,String> {


    public ImageDeployer(){

    }

    public ImageDeployer(HashMap<String, String> volIDMap, HashMap<String, String> osMap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.volIDMap = volIDMap;
    this.osMap = osMap;
    System.out.println(volIDMap);
    System.out.println(osMap);
    makeAConnection();
    try {
        doInBackground();
        System.out.println("Do In Background");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void makeAConnection(){

    inputFile = RESTEngine.getFilePath();
    Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        defaultProps.load(fin);
        fin.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
        System.out.println("The properties file supposed to contain Authorization parameters was not found.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1); 
    }
    catch(IOException e1){
        System.out.println("An exception occured while trying to open the properties file");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    // assign variables from Input file with default value as null
    user = defaultProps.getProperty("UserID", null);
    host = defaultProps.getProperty("PowerVC_IP_ADDRESS", null);
    password = defaultProps.getProperty("UserPass" ,null );

    jsch = new JSch();
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setInputStream(null);

        try {
            in = channel.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Unable to connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {

    ImageDeployer imageDeployer = new ImageDeployer();
    imageDeployer.makeAConnection();

    for(String imageName : volIDMap.keySet()){

        String volID = volIDMap.get(imageName);
        String oS = osMap.get(imageName);
        if (oS.equalsIgnoreCase("aix")){

            imageDeployer = new OVFImageDeployer(volID, oS, imageName);

        }
        // Other Cases depending upon the OS Type


    }
    return null;



}
}
```

The code for OVFImage Deployer

```
public class OVFImageDeployer extends PowerVCImageDeployer {

public OVFImageDeployer(String VolID,String oS,String imageName){

    String command="/usr/bin/powervc-devtools/powervc-devcli glance image-create json "+imageName+" "+oS+" "+VolID;

    try {


        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.connect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Now when I run the code I get a `NullPointerException` on line     `((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command)`.
I know if I put `makeAConnection` after the try block in `OVFImageDeployer` the code would work, but then I don't want to make a connection again and again . I want a connection to be initialized just once and all operations to be performed using that connection only.

Comment: where is your `channel` property defined? is it in `PowerVCImageDeployer`?

Comment: Yes, The channel is a variable of type Channel and is a public variable. I have made sure it is not method specific and declared it above
public class ImageDeployer extends SwingWorker<Boolean,String> .

Comment: and you want `channel` to be initialized when an instance of `ImageDeployer` is constructed and all method invocations on `ImageDeployer` instance should use the same `channel`? am i correct?

Comment: Yes, creating a Channel again and again would take a lot of time and resources .

Comment: You are calling `doInBackground` from inside `ImageDeployer` constructor and again you are creating an instance of `ImageDeployer` inside `doInBackground` method. Confusing! can you explain why?

Comment: Spot on . 
May be should not have done that. That's a mistake.
But I was trying to make sure that the instance of ImageDeployer which I am using to makeAConnection is the one which is cast into OVFImageDeployer so that the connection object remains initalized and I don't get a null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the call to `doInBackground` from inside the constructor of `ImageDeployer`:

```
public ImageDeployer(HashMap<String, String> volIDMap, HashMap<String, String> osMap) {
    ....
    makeAConnection();
    //doInBackground();
    ...
}
```

This will initialize the `channel` when you create an instance of `ImageDeployer`. And you can add `channel` to the list of constructor arguments of `OVFImageDeployer`:

```
public OVFImageDeployer(String VolID,String oS,String imageName, Channel channel){

this.channel = channel;
...
}
```

This will create an instance of `OVFImageDeployer` with the `channel` that is present in the `ImageDeployer` instance. You need to remove these two statements from inside the `doInBackground` method and pass `channel` along with the other parameters while constructing an instance of `OVFImageDeployer`:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {

//ImageDeployer imageDeployer = new ImageDeployer();
//imageDeployer.makeAConnection();
...
ImageDeployer imageDeployer = new OVFImageDeployer(volID, oS, imageName, channel);
...
}
```

Now the client code can create an instance of `ImageDeployer` and can execute `doInBackground` on it:

```
ImageDeployer imageDeployer = new ImageDeployer();
imageDeployer.doInBackground();
```

With this, every time you create an instance of `OVFImageDeployer` inside the `doInBackground` method, you can use the same `channel` which was created by the `makeAConnection` method while constructing the `ImageDeployer` instance.

Comment: Thanx , that works like a charm .
But it has now given me a new problem. A SwingWorker can be executed only once. So the OVFImageDeployer works only one time, it doesn't matter how many times the for loop is running
for(String imageName : volIDMap.keySet())
This loop is the new puzzle now